# Using XDocument to convert selected node to string

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have the following XML sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <GlobalResponses>
   <Filters>
     <FilterId>11</FilterId>
     <FilterId>5</FilterId>
     <FilterId>10</FilterId>
   </Filters>
   <Responses>
     <Response>
       <Name>Bob</Name>
     </Response>
     <Response>
       <Name>Jim</Name>
     </Response>
     <Response>
       <Name>Steve</Name>
     </Response>    
   </Responses>  
  </GlobalResponses>
```

Using XDocument, how can I get only the `<Responses>` parent and also child nodes, and convert them to a string variable.  I looked at XDocument Elements and Descendants, but by calling `oXDocument.Descendants("Responses").ToString();` didn't work.

Do I have to iterate over all of the XElements checking each one and then appending to a string variable ?

Comment: What format are you trying to get the result in? You've given us sample input - it would really help if you'd provide sample output too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `Descendants` returns enumeration of `XElement`, so you need to select specific element.

If you want to get XML element with all the child nodes, you can use:

```
// assuming that you only have one tag Responses.
oXDocument.Descendants("Responses").First().ToString();
```

The result is

```
<Responses>
  <Response>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
  </Response>
  <Response>
    <Name>Jim</Name>
  </Response>
  <Response>
    <Name>Steve</Name>
  </Response>
</Responses>
```

If you want to get child nodes and concatenate them to single string you can use

```
// Extract list of names
var names = doc.Descendants("Responses").Elements("Response").Select(x => x.Value);
// concatenate
var result = string.Join(", ", names);
```

The result is `Bob, Jim, Steve`

Answer (score 0):

The `Descendants()` method takes input the element name and it will return you a collection of nodes and from those you then further need to get the elements you are interested in.

You can use linq with `XDocument` to extract the information. For example, the following code with extract the `Name` element value from each `Response` node and prints out :

```
var nodes = from response in Doc.Descendants("Response")
            select response.Element("Name").Value;

foreach(var node in nodes)
    Console.WriteLine(node);
```

Here above `Doc.Descendants("Response")` will fetch all the `<Response>` elements and then we are using `response.Element("Name")` to fetch the `<Element>` tag for each `<Response>` element and then using `.Value` property we get the value between the tag.

[See this working DEMO fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IOumda).